# Sigma protocol compiler?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, implementation, sigma-protocol

Is there a well maintained, preferably documented, Sigma protocols compiler library? i.e. takes an abstraction of statements to prove, and outputs a cryptographic protocol between verifier and prover? 
A search yielded that [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221406504_Automatic_Generation_of_Sigma-Protocols), but it seems to point a library in which I don't find any code.

Comment: My two cents. Cryptographic protocols should be thoroughly thouth through. Then they will not  change very frequently. So, what is the real benefit having a compiler?

Comment: Your thought can be equivalently applied to all cryptographic schemes, and clearly there are many useful cryptographic compilers out there, which defeats your point.
Generally, compilers come to automate such processes which seem to fit into repetitive patterns. A witness to that claim is the attached paper itself...